# Unmatched braces when declaring a C# constructor

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a class constructor in C#, but Visual Studio wants a `}` right after the third `{`.

This is a part of my code:

```cs
namespace telefon
{
    class Hivas
    {
        public Hivas(string line)
        {
            public string[] lineIntArray = line.Split(" ").Select(int.Parse).Array();
        }
    }
}
```

I am probably just missing something, but I really can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare a `public` member inside the constructor. It must be directly in the class.